# Show Taxonomy Terms with Depth to Create Main Menu Dynamically

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm using views to create pages based on taxonomy terms and their child terms. I'd like to create a menu based on that output but don't know where to begin.

Comment: By menu, do you mean menu items that you want to also show up when you go to admin->structure->menu? or do you just want clickable anchor tags? you can do this easily with block.

Comment: @rwaery Well the problem I am having is we're using TB MegaMenu and the syntax it spits out is not working with what we have. Is there a way I can overwrite those TPL files? That's why I thought of doing it like I described above.

Comment: I havent yet used TB MegaMenu module. But if the menus are outputed in a form of drupal block, you can try using an alter hook, possibly hook_block_view_alter to replace the menu items with the taxonomy items you want.